# Question about the first step in Mann's original proof of the Schnirelmann-Landau Conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history, analytic-number-theory

I was reading Henry Mann's proof for the Schnirelmann-Landau Conjecture from 1942 which can be found in JSTOR [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968807)

Today, the Schnirelmann-Landau Conjecture is known as [Mann's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%27s_theorem#Mann.27s_theorem):

$$d(C) \ge \min(d(A)+d(B),1)$$

Here is how Mann defines his terms:

> Let $A(B,C)$ be sets of positive integers.  Form $A^0,B^0$ by adjoining $0$ to $A$ and $B$ respectively.  Let $A(n)$ be the number of positive integers in $A$ that are $\le n$.  The greatest lower bound of the quotients $A(n)/n$ is called the density of $A$.  Let $C^0$ consist of all integers of the form $a + b(a \in A^0,b \in B^0).$

Here's how defines $n_r$:

> Let $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ be the numbers of $\overline{C}$ (i.e. numbers not in $C$); then $C(n_r) = n_r - r$.

When it comes to the first step in the proof, Mann divides up $[1,n_r]$ into three sets:

> We divide up the numbers $\le n_r$ into three sets: numbers of $B$, numbers of the form $n_r - a(a\in{A^0})$, numbers of $L_r$ where $L_r$ denotes the set of all positive numbers $\le n_r$, that are neither in $B$ nor of the form $n_r - a(a \in{A^0})$.  Denote by $l_r$ the number of integers in $L_r$.  These three sets are disjoint.

How can we be sure that the numbers of $B$ and the numbers of the form $n_r - a(a\in{A^0})$ are disjoint?

For example, if $n_r=5, \{1,3\} \subseteq B, \{2\} \subseteq A$, then:

$B_{n_r} = \{1, 3\}, A_{n_r-a} = \{3\}, L_{r} = \{4\}$ which are not disjoint.

I am clearly missing one of Mann's assumptions.  What assumption does Mann make that guarantees that the three sets are [disjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets)?

Edit:  Thanks to Ted Shifrin, I've realized my misunderstanding!  My example above is wrong because of sumsets.  If $n_r = 5$, then $n_r - a \notin B$ since by assumption $n_r \notin C$ and $C = A + B$ where $+$ is the *sumset*.

Comment: Is there something specific about the numbers $n_r$ you haven't told us?

Comment: There is a section that talks about $n_r$ but my understanding is that it is solely used in determining the greatest lower bound.  He states his goal to prove:  $\frac{C(n_r)}{n_r} \ge \min \frac{A(n_q)+B(n_q)}{n_q}$ where $q \le r$.  Is there something there, you think?

Comment: This is far from my expertise. To download the paper, I need to go through some contortions with JSTOR. But, yes, I believe there's more going on to rule out your example.

Comment: He also says: "Let $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ be the numbers of $\overline{C}$ (i.e. numbers not in $C$); then $C(n_r) = n_r-r$"

Comment: Aha. That seems to be the crucial element. So no $n_r$ can be in $A+B$. Done :)

Comment: You are right!  I keep misunderstanding sumsets!  :-)

Comment: So you've edited, but still $2+3=5\in C$.